# how to parse date and time from timestamp in nuxt3

Tags: javascript, date, nuxt.js, date-fns, nuxtjs3

I want to parse date and time from the following time stamp in my Nuxt3 project using Date Fns.
on Date select on calender, this is the value we get.

```
const SelectedDate = "Sat Jul 02 2022 14:56:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I want to extract date and time from this, like.

```
Const Date = "02/07/2022"
Const Time = "14:56"
```

but i get wrong time, as result i get -

```
const Time = "14:07"
```

I have used this.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
import { format, compareAsc } from 'date-fns'
let pickdate = ref(new Date());

const FormattedDate = ref(format(pickdate.value, 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
const FormattedTime = ref(format(pickdate.value, 'HH:MM'))
</script>
```

Comment: The format of the timestamp is consistent with that produced by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring), so can be reliably parsed by the built–in parser, then [formatted however you wish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript).

Comment: What is wrong here? The `Date` one?